# What is the android browser virtual CSS resolution?

Tags: android, css

In iphone 4 the virtual CSS resolution is 1/4 of it's physical: `480-320`.
Does android browser (the one that comes with the OS and called "browser"), say in the most common devices that have `800-480` or `854-480` resolution, has a virtual resolution the CSS is scaled to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are MANY android browsers. More than 10. They are extremely different. I don't think they have anything in common except standard technologies as HTML, javascript, css, active components and so on.

Comment: I am talking about the android browser, that comes with the OS